# Invertibility of a square matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

Take a square matrix $A$ such that
$$
A=BDC,
$$
where $B,D,C$ are square matrices with all positive entrances; $D$ is a diagonal matrix with all entrances in the main diagonal positive.

Is it true that: if $A$ is invertible, then $B$ is invertible? Why?

Comment: Have you studied the rank of a product of matrices?

Comment: What happens if you multiply both sides on the right by $A^{-1}$?

Comment: @Théophile Thanks: I get $I=A^{-1}B DC $. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: That's multiplying on the left. :) Multiplying on the right gives $I = BDCA^{-1}$. You can see this as $I = B\left(DCA^{-1}\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\det(A)=\det(B)\det(D)\det(C)\ne0$$ and obviously $$\det(B)\ne0.$$

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter that the entries are positive or that $D$ is a diagonal matrix. From $$A=BDC,$$ multiply on the right by $A^{-1}$ to get $$I=BDCA^{-1}=B\left(DCA^{-1}\right).$$ In other words, $DCA^{-1}$ is the inverse of $B$.